# Strange NullReferenceException when debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I develop in VB.Net using Visual Studio Community Edition. From version 2015 on I noticed a strange behavior when debugging: if I halt execution with an interruption point and then make some changes in code, no matter how harmless (like editing a string, for instance ) VS will accept my changes but then it will halt again and that's because the variables that contained valid objects are now empty, that is, have the value of Nothing. Is that a known bug or is there something I can do to avoid or circumvent it? Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Editing code while the program is running is generally not a good practice.  This is because when you hit the "run" button in Visual Studio, the code is compiled in to assembly language that the computer can read and execute.

If you pause at a breakpoint and edit code, Visual Studio is not able to re-compile while in the middle of executing your program, and this is likely why your variable has "Nothing" in it.

One way to debug certain sections of code is to put the code you want to test into its own subroutine, and then have a button on your form (if using winforms) execute the subroutine.

Each time you edit your code, however, it is best to stop the program and hit run when you done making your edits so that VS will make a fresh build (compile) of your program.

Comment: I agree with your statement about I should avoid editing code "on the fly". However, this is awkward for VS 2013 didn't show this behavior, neither good old Visual Basic Express 2010. So, what did they (or should I do) differently here?

Comment: have you tried testing sections of your code in a subroutine?  I'm not sure that this is a bug in VS 2015 - I would think of it more as a security feature because it requires the program to be rebuilt before it is run again after an edit

Comment: The reasons for I suspect it is a bug, @Dustin, are these: 1. It happens in different places of my code which have nothing in common except the fact execution halted (due to exception or interruption point) and I made slight changes that don't cause VS to purple underline code - in this case there'd be no alternative than stop the run. 2. It never occurred in VS 2013, 2012 and 2010.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yty6a48.aspx - this tells about how to enable or disable the setting to be able to edit while debugging, which is what I think you are asking for

Comment: In my IDE, it gives one option with four sup-options. "Enable edit and continue" was already enabled, just like "Enable native edit and continue", "Apply alterations when continue (only native)" and "Warn about obsolete code (only native)". "Allow pre-compilation" was disabled, I enabled it now and let us see if it changes anything. Note: my IDE is in portuguese, so these above are my translations, I don't know if english interface uses the same exact words.